# How can I ensure range1 is smaller than range2?

Tags: c++, database, data-structures, structure

I am trying to ensure that int range1 must be smaller than int range2 before using this structure. I am new to programming.

```
struct prime
{
    int range1;
    int range2;
};
```

Comment: `prime p; /* initialize p */ assert(p.range1 < p.range2);`?

Comment: Are you saying that an empty range, e.g.: (0,0) is invalid?  Does "ensure" mean that incorrect values are corrected?  Or that an error is reported?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a constructor. Constructors are the place where you should make sure the object is constructed in a valid state:

```
struct prime
{
    prime(int a,int b) : range1(std::min(a,b)), range2(std::max(a,b)) {}
private:
    int range1;
    int range2;
};
```

I assumed you just want to make sure that `range1 < range2` but assume nothing about the passed parameters. If you want to make sure that `a < b` you could throw an exception when it is not the case.

Comment: OP may also want to research the terms **class invariant** and **encapsulation** to get a good understanding of the general principles at play here.